# Why can't I run this powershell script in a batch file?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

So when I run this script as administrator on powershell ise it works perfectly.

```
$ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$ComputerSystem.AutomaticManagedPagefile = $false
$ComputerSystem.Put()
$PageFileSetting = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting
$PageFileSetting.InitialSize = 12000
$PageFileSetting.MaximumSize = 32000
$PageFileSetting.Put()
```

But when I run this batch file below to run the script, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file "Memory.ps1"
```

Trying to change this [image]

To This [image]

Comment: Please expand on "it doesn't work." - was an error thrown? What was the exit code? Did the computer catch fire? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, If I right click the .ps1 script, click edit, and run Powershell ISE as administrator, it runs the script and changes the values I want to change. If you search "adjust the performance and appearance of windows" on taskbar, it opens the performance options tab, if you click the "Advanced" sub-tab in it, and click "Change" under virtual memory, it has the checkbox "Automatically manage paging size" checked. I want the initial and max size under the custom size button set to 12000 and 32000. Running the .bat file doesn't change the values. But running the script as admin does.

Comment: @randomguy2443, as you're clearly not invoking your powershell script elevated, I assume that you're running the batch file as administrator, would that be correct?

Comment: @Compo Yes running the batch file as administrator. I know I can change the permissions for power shell manually, but I'm trying to do a bypass through the batch file and then run the script so the manual editing isn't needed. Trying to get this script over to a few people in our department who aren't as technically adept or want to put in the effort to do it.

Comment: So back to the initial comment then, 'Please expand on "it doesn't work."'. I ask because my assumption is that in order for your new settings to work, you'd need to reboot your system. Also you could probably use these two lines from a batch file and just forget about powershell: `@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe ComputerSystem Where "Name='%ComputerName%'" Set AutomaticManagedPagefile=False`, and `@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe PageFileSet Where "Name='C:\\pagefile.sys'" Set InitialSize=12000,MaximumSize=32000`. You could even run those two lines with the `/User` and `/Password` options if necessary.

Comment: Here's the [DSC resource](https://github.com/dsccommunity/ComputerManagementDsc/blob/49beec359c838bf107a6cc932dcb572ec22954cd/source/DSCResources/DSC_VirtualMemory/DSC_VirtualMemory.psm1) that manages the page file settings. You could [use the DSC resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/configurations/configurations?view=powershell-7) or compare the underlying code to what you have.

Comment: @Compo Thanks! I was able to combine the two batch files you gave me and piece together a couple of other posts to get only the batch file to run and change the settings I wanted.

Comment: I only gave you one batch file @randomguy2443, I simply provided all of the lines, (a total of two), for it! I have now added those as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use these two lines from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) and just forget about [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe ComputerSystem Where "Name='%ComputerName%'" Set AutomaticManagedPagefile=False
@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe PageFileSet Where "Name='C:\\pagefile.sys'" Set InitialSize=12000,MaximumSize=32000
```

*You could even run those two lines with the `/User` and `/Password` options if necessary.*